Should an h3 or h4 ever go above an h2 if its semantic meaning is less significant?
I have a component that has an eyebrow and below the eyebrow there is a larger heading. The heading is larger and more significant to the overall theme of the component. The eyebrow is more supplementary.
Would it be allowable from an accessibility perspective to use an h3 or h4 for the eyebrow and an h2 for the heading text beneath it, even though the eyebrow is technically above the header?
For example,
 <section> 
   <h3 style="font-size: 12px">Eyebrow</h3> 
   <h2 style="font-size: 32px">Heading Element</h2>
 </section>


The code example in the question would violate WCAG Success Criterion 1.3.1 Info and Relationships: the visual formatting suggests that <h3 style="font-size: 12px">Eyebrow</h3> is a heading for what is below it, but the <h2 style="font-size: 32px">Heading Element</h2> (assuming </h4> is a typo) tells assistive technology that you have an empty section immediately followed by a higher-level heading (h2). At the level of meaning, the <h3 style="font-size: 12px">Eyebrow</h3>, so it should not be marked up as a heading.
What you really need is the hgroup element. Assuming h2 is the right heading level for the example, you would then have the following code:
 <hgroup>
   <p class="eyebrow">Eyebrow text here</p>
   <h2>Heading Element</h2>
 </hgroup>

This would not mess up the heading hierarchy when screen reader users browse by headings, for example by calling up the list of headings.

It can certainly be acceptable, but with caution.
Navigating by heading is one of the preferred way to navigate with a screen reader.

You can navigate from heading to heading, linearly, regardless of their level, in DOM order. Doing so, there is no problem, the H3 before the H2 will be found.
You can also navigate by headings of a given level, skipping all headings of lower levels. In this case, with your structure, there is a risk to completely miss the H3 when going through H2s.

So, if missing the H3 isn't that important and don't prevent from understanding the content in general, why not.
But if the H3 shouldn't be missed, putting it before the H2 is a very bad idea.
IF the H3 is before the H2 just because of visual design and hadn't really to be read before the H2, you should consider your choice very carefully. You can probably change the structure to put that H3 after the H2 and adapt your CSS accordingly.
If the H3 is after the H2, there is a lot less risks to miss it, and so it's much better for accessibility.
So, to wrap up: acceptable probably yes, recommended, certainly not.
Finally, note however that skipping levels, i.e. going directly from H2 to H4 without H3 is definitely incorrect. This is normally flagged by any decent automated tool.
